# angular 2 - Attempt to use a destroyed view

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I'm building an angular 2 app that fetch's data from server and display it with *ngFor.

When I click on a *ngFor item I change the route to different page. So far so good.. 
My problem occurs when I'm routing again to the *ngFor list (Not click on back, just go to the list through the menu bar).
First of all the list renders slower then the first time, Secondly when I click on *ngfor item again I`m getting the following error message:

[image]

I'm guessing its somehow regarding to a subscription that not been released when I first fetch's the data but I can`t find it anywhere...
I even try to detach the item component from the changeDetectionRaf and still I'm getting this error..

Comment: Hi @GiliYaniv, I'm having the same problem. Could you solve this?

Comment: Yes I did. I had an open observable inside the component instance that I didn't unsubscribe to it, And as long the subscriber is open the component is not really been destroyed.

Comment: I continued working after posting the question and found out that the problem was the same. Thanks anyway!